# Can't convert json to javascript object/array

Tags: javascript, json

I have this following lines in my page, and i want it to converti into javascript array/object. But I cannot help myself

```
<script language="javascript" src="json2.js"></script>
<script>
json={"status":"error","message":"there was an error","type":"unclassified"};
alert(json.stringify(json));
</script>
```

am i missing something?, i want to get the `"error"` value when i do `alert(newvar.error)` and i want to get the part "there was an error" when i do `alert(newvar.message)` that mean, the variable json, should be converted into javascript objects.

Comment: What you have is already a JavaScript object. It isn't JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want it to convert [JSON string] into javascript array/object

To do that you can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). To convert it back to a JSON string, you can use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

**Note:** What you have provided should already be a JavaScript object.

```
json={"status":"error","message":"there was an error","type":"unclassified"};
​alert(json.type);​
```

Comment: The question is malformed. That is why I added the quote.

Comment: i dont know, im very new to json.

Comment: @NicholasWild Well yes, you have to use `JSON.stringify(json)`, not `json.stringify(json)`. `json` doesn't have a stringify method.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script language="javascript" src="json2.js"></script>
<script>
jsona={"status":"error","message":"there was an error","type":"unclassified"};
jso=JSON.parse(jsona,false);
alert(jso);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Nicholas Wild, sorry. It was unclear what you are trying to do. The update should cover all your questions :)

Comment: it gives me all the text `{"status":"error","message":"there was an error","type":"unclassified"};` how is it converted into array or object?

Comment: @NicholasWild: It seems that you're trying to utilize JSON before understanding why it exists. Do you understand what JSON is used for?

Comment: You already have a JavaScript object. I don't believe you want to use `stringify`. You want to access the object. That is why I demonstrated `​alert(json.type);​`.

Comment: @user1689607, i just want to implement json because it is easier than xml and faster too, actually im learning json now, that is why i want to understand it, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are confused as to what JSON is. It is:

> a text format that is completely language independent but uses
>   conventions that are familiar to programmers of the C-family of
>   languages, including C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, Perl, Python, and
>   many others. These properties make JSON an ideal data-interchange
>   language.

Therefore:

```
json={"status":"error","message":"there was an error","type":"unclassified"};
```

is a javascript object.

This is JSON:

```
"{\"status\":\"error\",\"message\":\"there was an error\",\"type\":\"unclassified\"}"
```

Comment: It's not really even a representation of a "javascript object". It's more a representation of a generic data structure that can be parsed into whatever structure is appropriate for a given programming language.

Comment: While you are correct, it's name does mean JavaScript Object Notation.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right... and I hate that they gave it that name. It causes too much confusion.

Comment: It's like the Java in JavaScript...means absolutely nothing! I've updated my answer.

Comment: Agreed, and +1. Since you're updating, you may want to escape the inner quotes of your JSON example or change the outer ones to single. It'll make the formatting clearer.

Answer (score 1):

That is already an object. When you stringify it, you get a JSON representation of it. Also, the native object is JSON, not json.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to convert an object to JSON representation. Then you need:

```
JSON.stringify(json)
```

In Javascript variable names are case sensitive.

Comment: +1 for spotting and focusing on the bug.

Answer (score 0):

`json={"status":"error","message":"there was an error","type":"unclassified"};` **is** a JavaScript object.

You only need to parse JSON if it comes in the form of a string.

You only need to serialise a JavaScript object (with `JSON.stringify`, not a `stringify` method on an arbitrary object) if you want to convert it to a string containing a JSON text.